# Understanding memory allocation for large integers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, python-internals

How does Python allocate memory for large integers?

An `int` type has a size of `28 bytes` and as I keep increasing the value of the `int`, the size increases in increments of `4 bytes`.

1. Why `28 bytes` initially for any value as low as `1`?
2. Why increments of `4 bytes`?

PS: I am running Python 3.5.2 on a x86_64 (64 bit machine). Any pointers/resources/PEPs on how the (3.0+) interpreters work on such huge numbers is what I am looking for.

Code illustrating the sizes:

```
>>> a=1
>>> print(a.__sizeof__())
28
>>> a=1024
>>> print(a.__sizeof__())
28
>>> a=1024*1024*1024
>>> print(a.__sizeof__())
32
>>> a=1024*1024*1024*1024
>>> print(a.__sizeof__())
32
>>> a=1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024
>>> a
1152921504606846976
>>> print(a.__sizeof__())
36
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Why `28` bytes initially for any value as low as `1`?

I believe [@bgusach answered that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40344291/4952130) completely; Python uses `C` structs to represent objects in the Python world, any objects [including `int`s](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c30098c8c6014f3340a369a31df9c74bdbacc269/Include/longintrepr.h#L85):

```c
struct _longobject {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    digit ob_digit[1];
};
```

[`PyObject_VAR_HEAD`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject_VAR_HEAD) is a macro that when expanded adds another field in the struct (field [`PyVarObject`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyVarObject) which is specifically used for objects that have some notion of length) and, [`ob_digits`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fda4d710b0af74e1cf04108ed014e4eb42e84534/Include/longintrepr.h#L87) is an array holding the value for the number. Boiler-plate in size comes from that struct, for small *and* large Python numbers.

> Why increments of `4` bytes?

Because, when a larger number is created, the size (in bytes) is a multiple of the `sizeof(digit)`; you can see that in [`_PyLong_New`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fda4d710b0af74e1cf04108ed014e4eb42e84534/Objects/longobject.c#L183) where the allocation of memory for a new `longobject` is performed with `PyObject_MALLOC`:

```c
/* Number of bytes needed is: offsetof(PyLongObject, ob_digit) +
   sizeof(digit)*size.  Previous incarnations of this code used
   sizeof(PyVarObject) instead of the offsetof, but this risks being
   incorrect in the presence of padding between the PyVarObject header
   and the digits. */
if (size > (Py_ssize_t)MAX_LONG_DIGITS) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError,
                    "too many digits in integer");
    return NULL;
}
result = PyObject_MALLOC(offsetof(PyLongObject, ob_digit) +
                         size*sizeof(digit));
```

<sup>`offsetof(PyLongObject, ob_digit)` is the 'boiler-plate' (in bytes) for the long object that isn't related with holding its value.</sup>

`digit` is defined in the header file holding the `struct _longobject` as a `typedef` for `uint32`:

```
typedef uint32_t digit;
```

and `sizeof(uint32_t)` is `4` bytes. That's the amount by which you'll see the size in bytes increase when the `size` argument to `_PyLong_New` increases.

---

Of course, this is just how `C`Python has chosen to implement it. It is an implementation detail and as such you wont find much information in PEPs. The python-dev mailing list would hold implementation discussions if you can find the corresponding thread :-).

Either way, you might find differing behavior in other popular implementations, so don't take this one for granted.

Answer (score 18):

It's actually easy. Python's `int` is not the kind of primitive you may be used to from other languages, but a full fledged object, with its methods and all the stuff. That is where the overhead comes from.

Then, you have the payload itself, the integer that is being represented. And there is no limit for that, except your memory.

The size of a Python's `int` is what it needs to represent the number plus a little overhead.

If you want to read further, take a look at the [relevant part of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex):

> Integers have unlimited precision

Comment: Thanks. Is there a PEP that explains how this is done in the recent Python versions (3.0+)?

Comment: @Vigneshwaren It's an implementation detail of whatever interpreter you are using. Python-the-language only guarantees that an `int` has arbitrary precision, not how that is accomplished.

Comment: @Vigneshwaren: You can check basic info for CPython from [`sys.int_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.int_info) (`long_info` on 2.7). Basically, each `sys.int_info.bits_per_digit` of absolute magnitude (sign irrelevant), or portion thereof, requires an extra `sys.int_info.sizeof_digit` bytes to store. Note: Small `int`s are cached in CPython, so as an implementation detail, values from (IIRC) -5 to 256 are singletons; you only pay the 4-8 bytes for the pointer to reference them, not the cost of the object itself.