# Why is x**4.0 faster than x**4 in Python 3?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-internals

Why is `x**4.0` faster than `x**4`? I am using CPython 3.5.2.

```
$ python -m timeit "for x in range(100):" " x**4.0"
  10000 loops, best of 3: 24.2 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "for x in range(100):" " x**4"
  10000 loops, best of 3: 30.6 usec per loop
```

I tried changing the power I raised by to see how it acts, and for example if I raise x to the power of 10 or 16 it's jumping from 30 to 35, but if I'm raising by **10.0** as a float, it's just moving around 24.1~4.

I guess it has something to do with float conversion and powers of 2 maybe, but I don't really know.

I noticed that in both cases powers of 2 are faster, I guess since those calculations are more native/easy for the interpreter/computer. But still, with floats it's almost not moving. `2.0 => 24.1~4 & 128.0 => 24.1~4` **but** `2 => 29 & 128 => 62`

---

[TigerhawkT3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2617068/tigerhawkt3) pointed out that it doesn't happen outside of the loop. I checked and the situation only occurs (from what I've seen) when the **base** is getting raised. Any idea about that?

Comment: For what it's worth: Python 2.7.13 for me is a factor 2~3 faster, *and* shows the inverse behaviour: an integer exponent is faster than a floating point exponent.

Comment: @Evert yup, I got 14 usec for `x**4.0` and 3.9 for `x**4`.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

> Why is `x**4.0` *faster* than `x**4` in Python 3<sup>*</sup>?

Python 3 `int` objects are a full fledged object designed to support an arbitrary size; due to that fact, they are [handled as such on the C level](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L4051) (see how all variables are declared as `PyLongObject *` type in `long_pow`). This also makes their exponentiation a lot more *trickier* and *tedious* since you need to play around with the `ob_digit` array it uses to represent its value to perform it. ([Source for the brave.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L4148) -- See: [Understanding memory allocation for large integers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40344159/understanding-memory-allocation-for-large-integers-in-python) for more on `PyLongObject`s.)

Python `float` objects, on the contrary, *can be transformed* to a C `double` type (by using [`PyFloat_AsDouble`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/float.html#c.PyFloat_AsDouble)) and operations can be performed [using those native types](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L686). *This is great* because, after checking for relevant edge-cases, it allows Python to [use the platforms' `pow`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L784) ([C's `pow`, that is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow)) to handle the actual exponentiation:

```c
/* Now iv and iw are finite, iw is nonzero, and iv is
 * positive and not equal to 1.0.  We finally allow
 * the platform pow to step in and do the rest.
 */
errno = 0;
PyFPE_START_PROTECT("pow", return NULL)
ix = pow(iv, iw);
```

where `iv` and `iw` are our original `PyFloatObject`s as C `double`s.

> For what it's worth: Python `2.7.13` for me is a factor `2~3` faster, and shows the inverse behaviour.

The previous fact *also explains* the discrepancy between Python 2 and 3 so, I thought I'd address this comment too because it is interesting.

In Python 2, you're using the old `int` object that differs from the `int` object in Python 3 (all `int` objects in 3.x are of `PyLongObject` type). In Python 2, there's a distinction that depends on the value of the object (or, if you use the suffix `L/l`):

```
# Python 2
type(30)  # <type 'int'>
type(30L) # <type 'long'>
```

The `<type 'int'>` you see here *does the same thing `float`s do*, it gets safely converted into a C `long` [when exponentiation is performed on it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/intobject.c#L726) (The `int_pow` also hints the compiler to put 'em in a register if it can do so, so that *could* make a difference):

```c
static PyObject *
int_pow(PyIntObject *v, PyIntObject *w, PyIntObject *z)
{
    register long iv, iw, iz=0, ix, temp, prev;
/* Snipped for brevity */
```

this allows for a good speed gain.

To see how sluggish `<type 'long'>`s are in comparison to `<type 'int'>`s, if you wrapped the `x` name in a `long` call in Python 2 (essentially forcing it to use `long_pow` as in Python 3), the speed gain disappears:

```
# <type 'int'>
(python2) ➜ python -m timeit "for x in range(1000):" " x**2"       
10000 loops, best of 3: 116 usec per loop
# <type 'long'> 
(python2) ➜ python -m timeit "for x in range(1000):" " long(x)**2"
100 loops, best of 3: 2.12 msec per loop
```

Take note that, though the one snippet transforms the `int` to `long` while the other does not (as pointed out by @pydsinger), this cast is not the contributing force behind the slowdown. The implementation of `long_pow` is. (Time the statements solely with `long(x)` to see).

> [...] it doesn't happen outside of the loop. [...] Any idea about that?

This is CPython's peephole optimizer folding the constants for you. You get the same exact timings either case since there's no actual computation to find the result of the exponentiation, only loading of values:

```
dis.dis(compile('4 ** 4', '', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (256)
              3 POP_TOP
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Identical byte-code is generated for `'4 ** 4.'` with the only difference being that the `LOAD_CONST` loads the float `256.0` instead of the int `256`:

```
dis.dis(compile('4 ** 4.', '', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (256.0)
              2 POP_TOP
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

So the times are identical.

---

<sup>*All of the above apply solely for CPython, the reference implementation of Python. Other implementations might perform differently.</sup>

Comment: Whatever it is, it's related to the loop over a `range`, as timing only the `**` operation itself yields no difference between integers and floats.

Comment: The difference only appears when looking up a variable (`4**4` is just as fast as `4**4.0`), and this answer doesn't touch on that at all.

Comment: But, constants will get folded @TigerhawkT3 (`dis(compile('4 ** 4', '', 'exec'))`) so the time should be *exactly* the same.

Comment: Your last timings seem not to show what you say. `long(x)**2.` is still faster than `long(x)**2` by a factor of 4-5. (Not one of the downvoters, though)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 @JimFasarakis-Hilliard The question began on the simple question, without noticing that the effect is happening only in a loop (and when the index is involved in in the pow operation - `i**2` or `2**i`). But now, although there's a difference in the underline C code behavior, it doesn't seem to have such an affect on the pow operations when not on a running index. So how should we continue from here? the question changed, the answers are good but for the starting question. Would like to hear your advice on how to continue with the question, regarding the SO community standards.

Comment: @Graipher but that was my point. Objects of `<type long>` in Python `2` display the same speed discrepancy as they do in `Python 3` because they are implemented the same way. On the other hand, objects of `<type int>` in Python `2` (which *don't exist in Python 3*) are way speedier as people who've timed it have claimed.

Comment: @arieljannai outside a loop the values get folded by the interpreter so the operations are exactly the same, there's no additional computation required and no speed difference displayed.  What do you mean by running on an index? If you're talking about operations other than `pow` then, of course, those *would* display other behavior since they're implemented differently. Could you elaborate on what still troubles you with this answer?

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard Oh! the part that I was missing is that the interpreter handles it. What I meant with the index is that inside a loop, if I just run `2**17` or `2**17.0` there won't be such a difference, but if I'm using the loop variable (for `i` in ..) `i**17` will be much slower than `i**17.0`. But I believe that it still the same reason, since when it's a constant calculation the interpreter acts on it as if it was outside the loop and called a lot of times.

Comment: So when it's a constant calculations they are getting folded by interpreter (whether in a loop or not), but when a running index is involved - it's getting calculated in the loop and translated to what you've shown. Thanks!

Comment: So why did Python 3 make such a change if it has negative speed implications and can no longer use native types for integer operations?

Comment: @mbomb007 the elimination of the `<type 'long'>` type in Python 3 is probably explained by the efforts made to simplify the language. If you can have one type to represent integers it is more manageable than two (and worrying about converting from one to the other when necessary, users getting confused etc). The speed gain is secondary to that. The rationale section of [PEP 237](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/) also offers some more insight.

Comment: I'd like to throw out there that testing the Python 2 speed of `long(x) ** n` versus `x ** n` is a bit of a red herring, as you're explicitly casting the int `x` to a long. I'd be curious to see the speed comparison of `4L ** n` to `4 ** n`.

Comment: @pydsigner Good catch! You are indeed correct; I hadn't though of that. I don't want to deviate from the tests the OP used in his question so I'll just go on to state how fast `long(int_object)` is instead.

Answer (score 25):

If we look at the bytecode, we can see that the expressions are purely identical. The only difference is a type of a constant that will be an argument of `BINARY_POWER`. So it's most certainly due to an `int` being converted to a floating point number down the line.

```
>>> def func(n):
...    return n**4
... 
>>> def func1(n):
...    return n**4.0
... 
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (4)
              6 BINARY_POWER
              7 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis(func1)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (4.0)
              6 BINARY_POWER
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Update: let's take a look at [Objects/abstract.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/72dccde884d89586b0cafd990675b7e21720a81f/Objects/abstract.c) in the CPython source code:

```c
PyObject *
PyNumber_Power(PyObject *v, PyObject *w, PyObject *z)
{
    return ternary_op(v, w, z, NB_SLOT(nb_power), "** or pow()");
}
```

`PyNumber_Power` calls `ternary_op`, which is too long to paste here, so [here's the link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/72dccde884d89586b0cafd990675b7e21720a81f/Objects/abstract.c#L831).

It calls the `nb_power` slot of `x`, passing `y` as an argument.

Finally, in `float_pow()` at line 686 of [Objects/floatobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Objects/floatobject.c#L686) we see that arguments are converted to a C `double` right before the actual operation:

```c
static PyObject *
float_pow(PyObject *v, PyObject *w, PyObject *z)
{
    double iv, iw, ix;
    int negate_result = 0;

    if ((PyObject *)z != Py_None) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "pow() 3rd argument not "
            "allowed unless all arguments are integers");
        return NULL;
    }

    CONVERT_TO_DOUBLE(v, iv);
    CONVERT_TO_DOUBLE(w, iw);
    ...
```

Comment: why the downvote? conversion/variable type check seems to be the issue here. there's no speed difference with literals, between `12.0**40.0` and `12**40` for instance.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I believe that's due to constant folding.

Comment: I think the implication that there is a conversion and they aren't handled differently down the line "most certainly" is a bit of a stretch without a source.

Comment: I also thought that way but couldn't really find any source for it

Comment: From the documentation on *BINARY_POWER* it's also not very indicative to that subject, it's just taking from the stack and raising

Comment: @Mitch - Particularly since, in this particular code, there's no difference in the execution time for those two operations. The difference only arises with the OP's loop. This answer is jumping to conclusions.

Comment: Why are you only looking at `float_pow` when that doesn't even run for the slow case?

Comment: The difference only appears when looking up a variable (`4**4` is just as fast as `4**4.0`), and this answer doesn't touch on that at all.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: `4**4` and `4**4.0` get constant-folded. That's an entirely separate effect.

Comment: Would you change the line "it's most certainly due to an int being converted to a floating point number down the line"? Though a valid initial guess, this isn't the root cause (generally reformat your answer to include the update more gracefully.)

Answer (score 3):

Because one is correct, another is approximation.

```
>>> 334453647687345435634784453567231654765 ** 4.0
1.2512490121794596e+154
>>> 334453647687345435634784453567231654765 ** 4
125124901217945966595797084130108863452053981325370920366144
719991392270482919860036990488994139314813986665699000071678
41534843695972182197917378267300625
```

Comment: I don't know why that downvoter downvoted but I did because this answer doesn't answer the question. Just because something is correct does not in any way imply it is faster or slower. One is slower than the other because one can work with C types while the other has to work with Python Objects.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Well, I really thought it was obvious that it's faster to calculate just the approximation of a number to 12 or so digits, than to calculate all of them exactly. After all, the only reason why we use approximations is that they are faster to calculate, right?