# Why is the size of 2⁶³ 36 bytes, but 2⁶³-1 is only 24 bytes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython, python-internals

Everything in Python is an object. So the size of an int in Python will be larger than usual.

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(int())
24
```

OK, but why does it take 12 more bytes for `2⁶³` compared too `2⁶³ - 1` and not just one?

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(2**63)
36
>>> sys.getsizeof(2**62)
24
```

I get that `2⁶³` is a long and `2⁶³-1` an int, but why 12 bytes of difference?

No more intuitive, I tried some other things:

```
>>> a = 2**63
>>> a -= 2**62
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
36
```

`a` is still stored as a long even if it could be in an int now. So that's not surprising. But:

```
>>> a -= (2**63 - 1)
>>> a = 2**63
>>> a -= (2**63 - 1)
>>> a
1L
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
28
```

A new size.

```
>>> a = 2**63
>>> a -= 2**63
>>> a
0L
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
24
```

Back to 24 bytes, but still with a long.

Last thing I got:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(long())
24
```

**Question:**

How does the memory storage work in those scenarios?

**Sub-questions:**

Why is there a gap of 12 bytes to add what our intuition tells us is just 1 bit?

Why are `int()` and `long()` 24 bytes, but `long(1)` is already 28 bytes and `int(2⁶²)`?

*NB: Python 3.X is working a bit differently, but not more intuitively. Here I focused on Python 2.7; I did not test on prior versions.*

Comment: To one of those questions: Same reason `2.5 - 1.5` is a float, and not an int. Result is always the more complex type of the involved operands. In the case of `2**63 - 2**62` or any calculation invloving `int` and `long` the resulting type will be `long`

Comment: Very related if not dupe: [Understanding memory allocation for large integers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40344159/understanding-memory-allocation-for-large-integers-in-python)

Comment: @NH. Shame about the formatting of your comment. :(

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard: maybe a better dup target would be [Why do ints require three times as much memory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016610/why-do-ints-require-three-times-as-much-memory-in-python), which has an answer showing the C source for the python interpreter's data structures.

Comment: OP, you seem to be confusing (2^63) - 1 and 2^(63-1). Or at least after mentioning 2⁶³ - 1 you then work with 2\*\*62, which is **not** the same thing.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri, but now that I deleted my comment (to make the new one), you and Draco have to delete yours...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> why does it get 12 more bytes for 2⁶³ compared too 2⁶³ - 1 and not just one?

On an [LP64](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbcpx01/datatypesize64.htm) system<sup>1</sup>, a Python 2 `int` [consists of](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aa2adc828a0583ee472d42a3b6a8964c822c7ee2/Include/intobject.h#L23) exactly three pointer-sized pieces:

- type pointer
- reference count
- actual value, a C `long int`

That's 24 bytes in total. On the other hand, a Python `long` [consists of](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aa2adc828a0583ee472d42a3b6a8964c822c7ee2/Include/longintrepr.h#L90):

- type pointer
- reference count
- digit count, a pointer-sized integer
- inline array of value digits, each holding 30 bits of value, but stored in 32-bit units (one of the unused bits gets used for [efficient carry/borrow](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dd431b32f4a599fff9c9cddfe9d48cc66b347481/Objects/longobject.c#L2995) during addition and subtraction)

2**63 requires 64 bits to store, so it fits in three 30-bit digits. Since each digit is 4 bytes wide, the whole Python `long` will take 24+3*4 = 36 bytes.

In other words, the difference comes from `long` having to separately store the size of the number (8 additional bytes) and from it being slightly less space-efficient about storing the value (12 bytes to store the digits of 2**63). Including the size, the value 2**63 in a `long` occupies 20 bytes. Comparing that to the 8 bytes occupied by *any* value of the simple `int` yields the observed 12-byte difference.

It is worth noting that Python 3 only has one integer type, called `int`, which is variable-width, and implemented the same way as Python 2 `long`.

---

<sup>1</sup>
64-bit Windows differs in that it retains a 32-bit `long int`, presumably for source compatibility with a large body of older code that used `char`, `short`, and `long` as "convenient" aliases for 8, 16, and 32-bit values that happened to work on both 16 and 32-bit systems. To get an actual 64-bit type on x86-64 Windows, one must use `__int64` or (on newer compiler versions) `long long` or `int64_t`. Since Python 2 internally depends on Python `int` fitting into a C long in various places, `sys.maxint` remains `2**31-1`, even on 64-bit Windows. This quirk is also fixed in Python 3, which has no concept of *maxint*.

Comment: Is it correct that the 30-bit digits (4 bytes each) is exclusive to 64 bit systems? Would 32 bit systems use 15 bits, each taking up 2 bytes of memory?

Comment: @chrisz You should treat that as an implementation detail; the only way to tell is to look at the source of the interpreter/compiler in question and see what it does.

Comment: @chrisz Not necessarily, since 64-bit types and instructions are available on many 32-bit systems. As chepner said, it's an implementation details; but if you're curious, you can consult the source code.

Comment: Where can the data types implementation be found?

Comment: @CIsForCookies Take a look at the [headers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/longintrepr.h) and the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c).

Comment: @CIsForCookies: See also [Why do ints require three times as much memory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016610/why-do-ints-require-three-times-as-much-memory-in-python) for a look at some of the internals.  Although I still haven't found why Python only uses 30 bits of each "digit", and whether the digits are a base 2^30 or base-10^9 representation.  Either way requires manual carry propagation that can't compile to `add`/`adc`, but rather `add` / `cmp` / `adc` or similar.  (e.g. [like this extended-precision asm Fibonacci](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135618/30206))

Comment: @PeterCordes What makes you think the base is 10^9? `_PyLong_BASE` is defined as `1 << PyLong_SHIFT` (`PyLong_SHIFT` being 15 or 30), so it's definitely a power of 2. If you're referring to `_PyLong_DECIMAL_BASE`, that is only used for efficient conversion to decimal.

Comment: @user4815162342: thanks, I saw the decimal stuff and assumed it was always used.  The comments say the value of a number is `SUM(for i=0 through abs(ob_size)-1) ob_digit[i] * 2**(SHIFT*i)`, so you're right; it's base 2^30.  I don't understand why they wouldn't use all 32 bits, though, if using a power-of-2 radix.  That enables significantly more efficient arbitrary-precision operations, because the CPU generates carry-out on its own, so a chain of `add` / `adc` / `adc` ... works.  (That's the other reason I assumed decimal.)  It's clunky to express in C, though, and compilers aren't great.

Comment: @PeterCordes Retaining a bit for carry is a fairly standard trick for efficient addition of bignums in portable C. It's true that it doesn't compile to assembler that would use the processor's own carry flag, but it does lead to much faster code than the alternative, which is to precede each digit addition/subtractions with comparisons and branches. Instead, carry is simply obtained as [`sum >> PyLong_SHIFT`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dd431b32f4a599fff9c9cddfe9d48cc66b347481/Objects/longobject.c#L2995).

Comment: @user4815162342 that makes some sense if they decided not to use http://gmplib.org/ (asm optimized) functions for numbers that don't fit in a single `long`.  But using `sum >> shift` doesn't compile much more efficiently than `sum = a+b; carry_out = sum<b;` Unsigned compare into a 0/1 value in a register is not particularly slower than a mov and a shift on x86, and good compilers will actually turn that into `add` / `adc` (but then end up comparing into a register when they have to loop). MIPS has compare-into-register instructions, so there's no downside. Of course you don't branch on carry.

Comment: @PeterCordes They don't use gmplib because Python is as old as (or even older tnan) gmplib, and possibly also because Python has specific allocation requirements. I remember reports of some people trying gmplib and not getting speed increases, except on extremely large numbers. For that use case there is [a dedicated module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy).

Comment: @PeterCordes Even if branch prediction isn't involved, it's not obvious that shift+mask (with constants) would be slower than the comparison to a non-constant. But I guess that can be easily checked.

Comment: @user4815162342: Ah, I'm not too surprised that the extra overhead of a function call isn't worth it, even to [GMP's lightweight `mpn` functions](https://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions.html) that don't do any memory allocation.  The functions have lots of pointer args that the compiler has to put in registers instead of accessing with whatever addressing mode, and even just a function call at all clobbers registers.

Comment: @user48: Agreed that it's not *obvious*, but remember that the non-constant was an operand for `add`, so it's typically still in a register.  Turns out I actually already wrote an SO answer about [getting compilers to generate `adc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46701364/how-to-access-the-carry-flag-while-adding-two-64-bit-numbers-using-asm-in-c).  It's worse than I was remembering, and only clang actually used `adc` at all. Also, **[`sum<b` is only safe with no carry-in!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153852/assembly-adc-add-with-carry-to-c#comment53703145_4154170)** oops.

Comment: So TL;DR: the current shift design with base 2^30 is probably best if they aren't going to use (inline) asm or intrinsics.  Although base 2^60 or 2^63 would be twice as fast on 64-bit CPUs.  IDK how common it is for Python integers to be too large for a `long`, but only needing 90 bits or less.

Answer (score 5):

While I didn't find it in the documentation, here is my explanation.

Python 2 promotes `int` to `long` implicitly, when the value exceeds the value that can be stored in int. The size of the new type (`long`) is the default size of `long`, which is 32. From now on, the size of your variable, will be determined by its value, which can go up and down.

```
from sys import getsizeof as size
a = 1
n = 32

# going up
for i in range(10):
    if not i:
        print 'a = %100s%13s%4s' % (str(a), type(a), size(a))
    else:
        print 'a = %100s%14s%3s' % (str(a), type(a), size(a))
    a <<= n

# going down
for i in range(11):
    print 'a = %100s%14s%3s' % (str(a), type(a), size(a))
    a >>= n


a =                                                                                                    1 <type 'int'>  24
a =                                                                                           4294967296 <type 'long'> 32
a =                                                                                 18446744073709551616 <type 'long'> 36
a =                                                                        79228162514264337593543950336 <type 'long'> 40
a =                                                              340282366920938463463374607431768211456 <type 'long'> 44
a =                                                    1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542976 <type 'long'> 48
a =                                           6277101735386680763835789423207666416102355444464034512896 <type 'long'> 52
a =                                 26959946667150639794667015087019630673637144422540572481103610249216 <type 'long'> 56
a =                       115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936 <type 'long'> 60
a =              497323236409786642155382248146820840100456150797347717440463976893159497012533375533056 <type 'long'> 64
a =    2135987035920910082395021706169552114602704522356652769947041607822219725780640550022962086936576 <type 'long'> 68
a =              497323236409786642155382248146820840100456150797347717440463976893159497012533375533056 <type 'long'> 64
a =                       115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936 <type 'long'> 60
a =                                 26959946667150639794667015087019630673637144422540572481103610249216 <type 'long'> 56
a =                                           6277101735386680763835789423207666416102355444464034512896 <type 'long'> 52
a =                                                    1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542976 <type 'long'> 48
a =                                                              340282366920938463463374607431768211456 <type 'long'> 44
a =                                                                        79228162514264337593543950336 <type 'long'> 40
a =                                                                                 18446744073709551616 <type 'long'> 36
a =                                                                                           4294967296 <type 'long'> 32
a =                                                                                                    1 <type 'long'> 28
```

---

As you can see, the type stays `long` after it first became too big for an `int`, and the initial size was 32, but the size changes with the value (can be higher or lower [or equal, obviously] to 32)

So, to answer your question, the base size is 24 for `int`, and 28 for `long`, while `long` has also the space for saving large values (which starts as 4 bytes - hence 32 bytes for `long`, but can go up and down according to the value)

As for your sub-question, creating a unique type (with a unique size) for a new number is impossible, so Python has "sub classes" of `long` type, which deal with a range of numbers, therefore, once you over the limit of your old `long` you must use the newer, which accounts for much larger numbers too, therefore, it has a few bytes more.

Comment: The last paragraph is incorrect, or at least imprecise. There are no (Python-level) subclasses of `long`, just like there are no subclasses of `str` and `tuple`. `long` is simply one of those types whose each instance stores its size, much like `str`. `long` doesn't expose its size in `__len__`, but it's there nonetheless. The C API calls those [`PyVarObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/structures.html#c.PyVarObject).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. I just didn't know how to say that so I used sub-class with `"`...